# When is initWithCoder called on an NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a one-to-many relationship in core data, in which `Recipe` has a one-to-many relationship with `Step`.

When I try to fetch the saved recipes I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Step initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b30a20'
```

This is the code that fetches the recipes:

```
//Create the fetch request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

//Here is the entity whose contents we want to read
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

//Tell the request that we want to read the contents of the Recipe entity
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *requestError = nil;
//Execute the fetch request on the context
self.recipes = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];
```

It crashes only when I'm fetching the recipes, not when I'm creating and saving.

This is Step.h:

```
@class Recipe;

@interface Step : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id photo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * instruction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id timer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;

@end
```

Step.m:

```
@implementation Step

@dynamic photo;
@dynamic instruction;
@dynamic timer;
@dynamic recipe;
```

Recipe.h:

```
@class Step;

@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id ingredients;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *steps;

- (void) addIngredient: (NSString *) ingredient;
- (void) addIngredients:(NSArray *)ingredients;
- (BOOL) saveRecipe;

@end

@interface Recipe (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)insertObject:(Step *)value inStepsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromStepsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertSteps:(NSArray *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeStepsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInStepsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(Step *)value;
- (void)replaceStepsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withSteps:(NSArray *)values;
- (void)addStepsObject:(Step *)value;
- (void)removeStepsObject:(Step *)value;
- (void)addSteps:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
- (void)removeSteps:(NSOrderedSet *)values;

@end
```

Recipe.m:

```
@implementation Recipe

@dynamic image;
@dynamic ingredients;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic steps;

- (void) addSteps:(NSOrderedSet *)values
{
    NSMutableOrderedSet *tmpOrderedSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.steps];
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    NSUInteger valuesCount = [values count];
    NSUInteger objectsCount = [tmpOrderedSet count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < valuesCount; ++i) {
        [indexes addIndex:(objectsCount + i)];
    }
    if (valuesCount > 0) {
        [self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"Step"];
        [tmpOrderedSet addObjectsFromArray:[values array]];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmpOrderedSet forKey:@"Step"];
        [self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"Step"];
    }
}
```

Do I need to implement `initWithCoder:` in `Step`? If yes, what do I need to do in that method? Why and when is it called?

**Edit**: When I don't set the `image` attribute of `Recipe`, there's no crash. I don't see what it's got to do with `Step`. I set the `Recipe`'s image like this:

```
UIImage *squareImage = [self imageCrop:theImage];
recipe.image = squareImage;
```

This works and saves the recipe. Only when I fetch, the app crashes. It looks like `image` is being mixed up with `Step` somewhere. Also, I tried implementing `initWithCoder` in `Step`, and then got another crash when I was trying to do something with the image:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSOrderedSetM size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9891980'
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Set an "Exception breakpoint" and show the stack backtrace where the exception occurs.

Comment: Recipe is also an NSManagedObject right?

Comment: NSManagedObject doesn't conform to NSCoding, hence the initWithCoder method never gets called on them. There seems to be some problem in your implementation.

Comment: @Adithya yes, Recipe is an NSManagedObject.

Comment: You don't implement initWithCoder on managed objects. Something odd is going on. Are you using an unusual persistent store type or something?

Comment: Does the implementation of Recipe have anything in it other than @dynamic statements?

Comment: @jrturton I haven't changed anything of the automatically generated code in the app delegate class. I'll post my implementation of Recipe here.

Comment: What is `self` in `self.recipes = …`? Where is a "Step" object in your code? Are any attributes defined as "Transformable"?

Comment: `self` is the app delegate. The Step object is used in a view controller class where I save the recipe. The `Step` and `Recipe` entities have some attributes defined as transformable.

Comment: What are the transformable attributes and what do you assign to them (and why are they needed at all?). - Have you specified a custom value transformer? Otherwise the object assigned to the transformable attribute must conform to the NSCoding protocol.

Comment: I assign a `UIImage` and an `NSArray` to the transformable attributes. I haven't specified a custom value transformer (I'm not sure what that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo in one of the methods and the crash was occurring because of a memory corruption. The crash log revealed nothing related to the typo!

In the `addSteps:` method in Recipe.m, I was using the class name `Step` instead of the property name `steps`.

It should have been like this:

```
[self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"steps"];
[tmpOrderedSet addObjectsFromArray:[values array]];
[self setPrimitiveValue:tmpOrderedSet forKey:@"steps"];
[self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"steps"];
```

instead of:

```
[self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"Step"];
[tmpOrderedSet addObjectsFromArray:[values array]];
[self setPrimitiveValue:tmpOrderedSet forKey:@"Step"];
[self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:indexes forKey:@"Step"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called when you archive custom objects. This [link](http://www.mentalfaculty.com/mentalfaculty/Blog/Entries/2010/4/17_Keyed-Archiving_to_Core_Data_Migration.html) can help you understand it

In the above code you have custom Object type "Recipe" in "Step". This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539619/storing-custom-objects-with-core-data) will help you

Your Recipe class should be as show below for archiving, which is to communicate using key value pairs with data types.

Those method are part of archiving process and un-archiving process.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
//read
if(self = [super init]){
    property1=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property1"];
}
return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
//save
[encoder encodeObject:property1 forKey:@"property1"];
}
```

Comment: But I don't think I'm archiving a `Step` object.

Comment: Do I need to implement `NSCoding` in `Recipe` or `Step`?

Comment: You don't do this for managed objects. Serialisation and deserialisation are taken care of by the persistent store coordinator.